# Deleting a function definition causes link errors but deleting its declaration is okay

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm currently cleaning up some old code and found a function `FormatString` that is not called anywhere. So I decided to remove it from its header and source files.

I first removed it from the header and tried to compile just to be sure that it isn't used anywhere else in the project. It successfully compiled so I decided to delete its definition in the source file as well.

But for some reason, I get a link error (LNK2001 on MVS2015).
When I checked the link error, the `unresolved external symbol` message is pointing to the function `GetSomeOtherString`.

I don't understand why this is the case because as long as I only delete the header declaration, there is no problem. Without the header declaration, I am assuming the function is now usable only in its source file and since the file is small (only 50 lines), I can easily see that it is not called anywhere.

I am unsure where the problem lies so I tried to duplicate the files as much as possible.

header.h

```
namespace NA {
    std::wstring GetSomeString();
    std::wstring GetSomeOtherString(const std::wstring &key);
    std::wstring FormatString(const std::wstring &key, ...);
    void SomeFunction();
}
```

source.cpp

```
namespace NA {
    inline std::wstring GetSomeString() { return L"SomeString"; };
    inline std::wstring GetSomeOtherString(const std::wstring &key) { 
        //return L"" if key has no value in someMap;
        return someMap[key]; 
    }
    std::wstring FormatString(const std::wstring &key, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, std::wstring(key));
        std::wstring formattedString = L"";
        //do formatting
        va_end(args);
        return formattedString;
    }
    void SomeFunction() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

If it matters, here is how the code that uses GetSomeOtherString looks like. (It is on another source file but in the same project)

```
namespace {
    inline std::wstring SomeOtherFunction (const std::wstring& key) {
        //some code
        std::wstring x = NA::GetSomeOtherString(key);
        //some code
    }
}
```

EDIT:

After trying to look for the simplest code that can duplicate this problem, I finally found an answer. What was missing from my original post (and what I foolishly overlooked) was that `GetSomeOtherString` is called inside `FormatString`.

```
    std::wstring FormatString(const std::wstring &key, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, std::wstring(key));
        std::wstring formattedString = L"";
        GetSomeOtherString(key); //<-- HERE
        //do formatting
        va_end(args);
        return formattedString;
    }
```

I find that if I erase the `inline` keywords in the source file, I can compile it successfully even if I delete the `FormatString` function definition. (I also don't know why the original programmer put `inline` keywords here.)

But if I put the `inline` keywords again, it will only compile if I add a function that uses the `inline`-ed function.

What is going on here?

Comment: Does your attempt at duplication in a separate project with the source listed here also exhibit the same symptom?

Comment: Don't have `inline` on the definitions in source.cpp  while also having a non-inline declaration in the header

Comment: To clarify, you know that `SomeOtherFunction` calls `NA::GetSomeOtherString`, but you can't understand why deleting the body for `NA::GetSomeOtherString` causes link errors?

Comment: @WhozCraig unfortunately, no. I'm currently trying to duplicate it but so far, no luck.

Comment: @M.M No, sorry if my question was confusing. I know that `SomeOtherFunction` calls `NA::GetSomeOtherString`, but I can't understand why deleting the body for `NA::FormatString` causes link errors even though `FormatString` is not called anywhere as far as I know.

Comment: @yushi Maybe it is called and you didn't see the call?